# Move PopUp from background to foreground

Tags: javascript, jquery, background, popup

I open a popup with this code:

```
$('a[href^="/foto/"]').live ('click', function (e)
{
    e.preventDefault ();
    // open popup
    window.open (
        $(this).attr ('href'),
        'imgPreview',
        'width=1050,height=902,scrollbars=yes,menu=yes,toolbar=no'
    );
});
```

This code works as intended but if the popup window is in the background and I click on another link which starts with /foto/, the popup stays in the background. So it is possible to not realize that the photo is already shown in the popup.

Is it possible to move the photo popup from the background to the foreground if I click on a link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, `window.focus()` would do the trick:

```
$('a[href^="/foto/"]').live ('click', function (e)
{
    e.preventDefault ();
    // open popup
    var win=window.open (
        $(this).attr ('href'),
        'imgPreview',
        'width=1050,height=902,scrollbars=yes,menu=yes,toolbar=no'
    );
    win.focus();
});
```